# Lookup for a value, find its adjacent cell's value and change that cell's value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

[image: Excel Screenshot]

In this table, I have some data:

- I want to lookup for a value(from `D7`)  in column A
- find  its adjacent from column `C` (print it in `E7`)
- and change this column `C`'s cell's value to a New Value(from `F7`).

Till now I have found a way to lookup for value and find its adjacent cell  using `=VLOOKUP(D7,A1:C4,3,0)` in E7.

Now If I write something in F7 it should change value in Col C which we found in E7.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You will need VBA to achieve this.

Comment: As an aside, I would NEVER use VLOOKUP. Instead use INDEX/MATCH. It is faster and more robust as it does not break if you insert or delete columns. So in this case it would be `INDEX(C1:C4,MATCH(D7,A1:A4,0))`. Once you get used to the syntax, it is easier to use than VLOOKUP because you don't have to count columns and you can immediately see what columns you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to achieve with pure formulas. The [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) solution is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim temp As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7")) Is Nothing Then
        Set temp = Range("A1:A4").Find(Trim(Range("D7")), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not temp Is Nothing Then
            Range("E7") = temp.Offset(0, 2)
            temp.Offset(0, 2) = Range("F7")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]